# When are numerical expressions identical

Tags: evaluation

Very elementary:

`2 + 3 == 5`   evaluates to `True` and `5 == 5`   evaluates to `True`.

How do I check if two numerical expressions are identical?

In other words, I want  a matching test that says `2 + 3` does not match `5`, but `5` does match `5`.
More generally, how do you test whether algebraic expressions are identical?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a try for the first question:

```
reallySameQ[a_, b_] := SameQ[Hold[a], Hold[b]]
SetAttributes[reallySameQ, HoldAllComplete]
reallySameQ[5, 5]
(* True *)
reallySameQ[2 + 3, 5]
(* False *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Following WReach's fine explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6169506/618728) one cannot even rely on [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) to check for identical expressions; instead it seems one needs [`Order`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Order.html), therefore with holding added:

```
SetAttributes[identicalQ, HoldAll]

identicalQ[x_, y_] := Order[Unevaluated @ x, Unevaluated @ y] == 0
```

Now:

```
identicalQ[2 + 3, 5]

identicalQ[5, 5]
```

> ```
> False
>
> True
> ```

Comment: I was waiting for your response :D, +1 ^^

Comment: @Mr.Wizard can into much upvotes! Though admittedly, WReach`s answer dissapoints me. You read things like that, then you want to go hide under a rock and kill yourself, because nothing makes sense anymore.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I admit that his answer reveals a less clean world that one would like, and it may come as a shock, but at the same time it makes the case for why such things are difficult to handle.  *Most* of the time it seems to work out OK, and with Mathematica's exact/symbolic and arbitrary precision capabilities there are more solutions available to us than (easily) to most programmers.

Comment: `Tally` spawning 3 examples of `2.2...006` and putting them in different groups was what really made my day though.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I had forgotten about that part.